# Eagle PCB supply symbols in a multi-voltage system

Tags: power-supply, eaglecad

Supply symbols signify vdd and gnd and perhaps vdd, gnd and vss in dual supply system.

However, in a situation where one has +5V, -5V, +3.3V, 1.8V, Analogue ground and Digital ground, what should one do about the symbols? There do seem to be 2 ground symbols so ground is not an issue but not many other symbols for nonground supply rails.

Expanding on this question if I am creating a "multi design" PCB with multiple +5V rails, +3.3V rails and grounds where every design has its own area on the PCB with no interaction with other designs, how does one use supply symbols in that case?

Comment: Eagle comes with many different symbols for these voltages.
You can name the symbol and re-name its connected nets.

Comment: You can create your own symbols for power and ground, based on a shape of your choice. You have to have at least one wire with a net name and connection properties. I created 'star' grounds that way so the PCB layout was much easier.

Comment: could you elaborate on this star ground, is this where we have seperate digital and analogue grounds?

Comment: See the question: How can you add custom supply symbols in Eagle?

Answer (score 2):

In the supply2 library, there are different +5V Symbols you can use those. (If you are a more advanced user you can modify the library and create your own.)

Another way is to use the NAME command and Label each net with XREF, this way it looks quite nice and you can select your own names e.g. +5V/1, +5V/2.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer the textural annotation near the standard symbol. Otherwise you need to remember what particular symbol means. It is painful if the schematics is given in the paper form and you need to check 100 times what the voltage is